# How to write Qt plugin system with bindings in other languages?

Tags: java, c++, python, qt, plugins

I am writing an application in Qt that I want to extend with plugins.
My application also has a library that the plugins will use. So, I need a 2 way communication. Basically, the plugins can call the library, and my application which loads the plugins will call them.

Right now, I have my library written in C++, so it has some classes. The plugins can include the header files, link to it and use it. I also have a header file with my interface, which is abstract base class that the plugins must have implemented. They should also export a function that will return a pointer to that class, and uses C linkage.

Up to this point I believe that everything is clear, a standard plugin interface. However, there are 3 main problems, or subtasks:

1. How to use the library from other languages?
   I tried this with Python only. I used SIP to generate a Python component that I successfully imported in a test.py file, and called functions from a class in the library. I haven't tried with any other language.
2. How to generate the appropriate declaration, or stub, for my abstract class in other languages? Since the plugins must implement this class, I should be able to somehow generate an equivalent to a header in the other languages, like .py files for Python, .class files for Java, etc.
   I didn't try this yet, but I suppose there are generators for other languages.
3. How am I going to make instances of the objects in the plugins? If I got to this point the class would be implemented in the plugins. Now I will need to call the function that returns the instance of the implemented abstract class, and get a pointer to it.
   Based on my research, in order to make this work I will have to get a handle to the Python interpreter, JVM, etc., and then communicate with the plugin from there.

It doesn't look too complex, but when I started my research even for the simplest case it took a good amount of work. And I successfully got only to the 1st point, and only in Python. That made me wonder if I am taking the right approach? What are your thoughts on this.. maybe I should not have used Qt in my library and the abstract base class, but only pure C++. It could probably make the things a bit easier. Or maybe I should have used only C in my library, and make the plugins return a C struct instead of a class. That I believe would make the things much easier, since calling the library would be a trivial thing. And I believe the implementation of a C struct would be much easier that implementing C++ class, and even easier that implementing a C++ class that uses Qt objects.

Please point me to the right direction, and share your expertise on this. Also, if you know of any book on the subject, I'd be more than happy to purchase it. Or some links that deal with this would do.

Comment: Which languages do you want to support?

Comment: Right now, I'd like to support Java and Python. Later, if it's not very complicated I would support more.

Answer (score 1):

C++ mangles its symbols, and has special magic to define classes, which is sort of hacked on top of standard (C) object files. You don't want your files from other languages to understand that magic. So I would certainly follow your own suggestion, to do everything in pure C.

However, that doesn't mean you can't use C++. Only the *interface* has to be C, not the implementation. Or more strictly speaking, the object file that is produced must not use special features that other languages don't use.

While it is possible for a plugin to link to your program and thus use functions from it, I personally find it more readable (and thus maintainable) to call a plugin function after loading it, passing an array of function pointers which can be used by the plugin.

1. Every language has support for opening shared object (SO or DLL) files. Use that.
2. Your interface will consist of functions which have several arguments and return types, which probably have special needs in how they are passed in or retrieved. There probably are automated systems for this, but personally I would just write the interface file by hand. The most important is that you properly document the interface, so people can use any language they want, as long as they know how to load object files from their language.
3. Different languages have very different ways of storing objects. I would recommend to make the creator of the data also the owner of the memory. So if your program has a class with a constructor (which is wrapped in C functions for the plugin interface), the class is the one creating the data, and your program, not the plugin, should own it. This means that the plugin will need to notify your program when it's done with it and at that point your program can destroy it (unless it is still needed, of course). In languages which support it, such as Python and C++, this can be done automatically when their interface object is destroyed. (I'm assuming here that the plugin will create an object for the purpose of communicating with the actual object; this object behaves like the real object, but in the target language instead of C.)

Keep any libraries (such as Qt) out of the interface. You can allow functions like "Put resource #x at this position on the screen", but not "Put this Qt object at this position on the screen". The reason is that when you require the plugin to pass Qt objects around, they will need to understand Qt, which makes it a lot harder to write a plugin.

If plugins are completely trusted, you can allow them to pass (opaque) pointers to those objects, but for the interface that isn't any different from using other number types. Just don't require them to do things with the objects, other than calling functions in your program.